# Data Getting from Webservice Showing in Listview, then Sort the Listview Custom Adapter Based on a item in List

Tags: android

In My Listview having 5 data,but Based On Km Distance Double Value ,sort the Full Listview in Ascending Order. All data fetching from Webservice. Showing Data In Listview Working But only Last Row Data Showing In Full List How to Resolve it Help me

```
package com.example;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.Rating;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Find_Stores_1_Distance_Based_Tabview1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    ListView listPage;
    Button Near_Me, Top_Service, Rating_Based, Add_ServiceCenter;
    View rootView;


    int[] images = {
            R.drawable.shop1,R.drawable.shop2,R.drawable.shop1,
            R.drawable.shop1,R.drawable.shop2,R.drawable.shop1,
            R.drawable.shop1,R.drawable.shop2,R.drawable.shop1}

    Rating rateme;

    float ratingValue = 2.0f;


    String ServiceModel = " Phone ";


    // for WebService Fetch from web to Find stores ..
            private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "************";
            private static final String NAMESPACE = "************";
            private static final String URL = "************";
            private static final String METHOD_NAME = "************";
            private String TAG2 = "************";
            public static String Status_Response_FindStores_Landing = "";


            // for WebService Fetch from web to Find stores ..
            private static final String SOAP_ACTION1 = ""************"";
            private static final String NAMESPACE1 = ""************"";
            private static final String URL1 = ""************"";
            private static final String METHOD_NAME1 = ""************"";
            private String TAG3 = ""************"";
            public static String Status_Res_FindStores_Showpage_Data = "";      



            public  String Center_id,Brand_name, ServiceCenterName,Address1,EMailId,ContactNumber,Pincode,Cityname,Latitude1,Longitude1;

            public  String Center_id2,Brand_name2, ServiceCenterName2,Address2,EMailId2,ContactNumber2,Pincode2,Cityname2;

            // flag for Internet connection status
                Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
                // Connection detector class
                InternetConnectionDetector cd1;


                // Progress Bar
                ProgressBar pg;

                private ProgressDialog progress;


                   String[] SERVICE_CENTERNAME,Full_ADDRESS,CENTER_ID;

                   String[] KM_DISTANCE_StringArray;

                   TextView CenterIDText;


                 public String CategoryStringItem,BrandStringItem,CityStringItem;
                 public TextView NotfoundText1; 
                 public Button ReloadButton1;

                public  String centerId_Service,LatitudeSingle_Service,LangitudeSingle_Service;





                public String Latittude_LogitutdeString;

                double latitude_Current, longitude_current;

            //  public Float distance;
                public double distance1;


                    GPSTracker gps;

                 boolean _areLecturesLoaded = false;

                 //For Creating Double array;
                 String[] LatitudeArray,LangitudeArray;



                 public static int StatusoutPutInteger1;

                 //For Ascending Order  Sort

                  private boolean mAscendingOrder[] = {true, true, true};
                    private ItemsListAdapter mAdapter;





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.find_stores_1_distancebased_tabview1,container, false);

        // creating connection Detector class for checking Internet Status
        cd1 = new InternetConnectionDetector(getActivity());

        // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());


        // call the views with this layout
        listPage = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView123);

         mAdapter = new ItemsListAdapter();


      //  ((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView123)).setAdapter(mAdapter); 

        listPage.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //    fillShoppingList();

        return rootView;

    }

    public void onResume() 
    {
        try {
            super.onResume();


            // get Internet status
            isInternetPresent = cd1.isConnectingToInternet();
            // check for Internet status
            if (isInternetPresent) 
            {

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                     latitude_Current = gps.getLatitude();
                     longitude_current = gps.getLongitude();


                    // for data Fetch from web
                    AsyncCallWSfor_PRODUCT task = new AsyncCallWSfor_PRODUCT();
                    // Call execute
                    task.execute();

                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }


            } 
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Check Your Internet Connection ..!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Exception in Tab1 Onresume","Error");

        }

    }


    // for Product Web Sync 
    private class AsyncCallWSfor_PRODUCT extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            Log.i(TAG2, "doInBackground");
            try
            {
                getSignupdata1(CategoryStringItem,BrandStringItem,CityStringItem);

            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"error caught in do in background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i(TAG2, "Error in Find Background");
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;

            // return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            //pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            // To dismiss the dialog
            progress.dismiss();

            Log.i(TAG2, "onPostExecute");

            try {

                    // Show items ascending

                    mAdapter.sortByPriceAsc();

                    listPage.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View views,int position, long id)
                        { 

                            try {

                                // get Internet status
                                isInternetPresent = cd1.isConnectingToInternet();
                                // check for Internet status
                                if (isInternetPresent) 

                                        // for Service Center Show page Data Fetch from web
                                        AsyncCallWSfor_FETCHService_Center task = new AsyncCallWSfor_FETCHService_Center();
                                        // Call execute
                                        task.execute();     

                                } 
                                else
                                {

                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Check Your Internet Connection..!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

                            } catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.i("Exception in Tab1 OnItemClick","Error");

                            }

                        }
                    });



                }




            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG2, "Error in Product Insert");
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error in sucess",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        { 
            progress.setTitle("Progress");
            progress.setMessage("Please Wait Loading...");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG2, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }

    public void getSignupdata1(String Categoryitem,String Branditem, String CityLocation) 
    {
        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo pi3 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi3.setName("Categ");
        pi3.setValue(Categoryitem);// get the string that is to be sent to the webservice
        pi3.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi3);

        PropertyInfo pi4 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi4.setName("Band");
        pi4.setValue(Branditem);// get the string that is to be sent to the webservice
        pi4.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi4);

        PropertyInfo pi5= new PropertyInfo();
        pi5.setName("City");
        pi5.setValue(CityLocation);// get the string that is to be sent to the webservice
        pi5.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi5);

        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            // Invole web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            // Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();




            if ((response.toString()).contains("{")) 
            {
                // JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(response);
                SoapObject rep = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(rep.getPropertyAsString(0));
                for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);

                       Center_id = jb.getString("CenterId");
                       Brand_name = jb.getString("Brand");
                       ServiceCenterName = jb.getString("Center");
                       Address1 = jb.getString("Add");
                       EMailId = jb.getString("mail");
                       ContactNumber = jb.getString("Contact");
                       Pincode = jb.getString("PinCode");
                       Cityname = jb.getString("City");
                       Latitude1=jb.getString("latitude");
                       Longitude1=jb.getString("longitude");

                       double latitude_Doublevalue = Double.parseDouble(Latitude1);
                       double longitude_Doublevalue = Double.parseDouble(Longitude1);


                       try
                       {

                        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
                        locationA.setLatitude(latitude_Current);
                        locationA.setLongitude(longitude_current);
                        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
                        locationB.setLatitude(latitude_Doublevalue);
                        locationB.setLongitude(longitude_Doublevalue);
                //      distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000;//Distance in Kilometers



                        distance1 = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000;



                         Log.i("Service_CenterNameStringOutput","Out "+ServiceCenterName);
                         Log.i("AddressStringOutput","Out "+Address1);
                         Log.i("DistanceStringOutput","Out "+distance1);


                       }
                       catch(Exception ex)
                       {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                           Log.i(TAG2, "Error in Distance Calculate");

                       }

                       getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {



                                fillShoppingList(Address1,ServiceCenterName,distance1);


                            }
                        });  

                     //  Log.i("CenterIdssss", Center_id);

                }



            } 
            else
            {
                Status_Response_FindStores_Landing = response.toString();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG2, "Error in Signup1 catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    //GPS Enabler
         public void showSettingsAlert() {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());
                alertDialog.setTitle("Settings");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Enable Location Provider! Go to settings menu?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();

            }






         private void fillShoppingList(String address12, String serviceCenterName3, double distance12string  )
            {


                SortAscendingClass item = new SortAscendingClass();
                item.setAddressArray(address12);
                item.setCmpy_NameArray(serviceCenterName3);
                item.setDistancekmArray(distance12string);

                mAdapter.addItem(item);
                //mAdapter.sortByPriceAsc();

            }



            /** Adapter for the shopping list items */
            private class ItemsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

                private LayoutInflater vi;
                private ArrayList<SortAscendingClass> shoppingList = new ArrayList<SortAscendingClass>();

                public ItemsListAdapter() 
                {

                      vi = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                }

                /** Add white line */
                public void addItem(SortAscendingClass item) {
                    shoppingList.add(item);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }



                /** Sort shopping list by price ascending */
                public void sortByPriceAsc() {
                    Comparator<SortAscendingClass> comparator = new Comparator<SortAscendingClass>() {

                        @Override
                        public int compare(SortAscendingClass object1, SortAscendingClass object2) {
                            return Double.compare(object1.getDistancekmArray(), object2.getDistancekmArray());
                        }
                    };
                    Collections.sort(shoppingList, comparator);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }




                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    ViewHolder holder = null;
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.findstores_service_center_tabview1_2_3_listview, null);



                        holder.myImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        holder.ServcieCenterFullname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        holder.AddressName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        holder.ratingtext = (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarinTabs);
                        holder.myDistance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Distance);
                        holder.SErvice_Available = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serviceCategory);

                        /*holder.CenterIDText=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.CenterId_xml);
                        holder.LatitudeText=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.latitude_xml);
                        holder.LangitudeText=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.langitude_xml);*/


                        convertView.setTag(holder);
                    }
                    else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }


                        holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
                        holder.ServcieCenterFullname.setText(String.valueOf(shoppingList.get(position).getCmpy_NameArray()));
                        holder.AddressName.setText(String.valueOf(shoppingList.get(position).getAddressArray()));
                        holder.ratingtext.setRating(ratingValue); // to set rating value
                        holder.myDistance.setText(String.valueOf(shoppingList.get(position).getDistancekmArray()+" Km"));
                        holder.SErvice_Available.setText(ServiceModel);




                    return convertView;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {

                    return shoppingList.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {

                    return shoppingList.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {

                    return position;
                }

                /** Helper class acting as a holder of the information for each row */
                private class ViewHolder {
                    /*public TextView name;
                    public TextView price;
                    public TextView quantity;*/

                        public ImageView myImage;
                        public TextView ServcieCenterFullname;
                        public TextView AddressName ;
                        public RatingBar ratingtext ;
                        public TextView myDistance;
                        public TextView SErvice_Available;
                        public TextView CenterIDText;
                        public TextView LatitudeText;
                        public TextView LangitudeText;

                }
            }


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort listview items in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187504/how-to-sort-listview-items-in-descending-order)

Comment: There must be some data hold by your adapter in form of array or other. You need to sort it out items by making your own comparison function and refresh listview. Voila!

Comment: I Have Added my code Problem Help me to Resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Collections and ArrayList also to sort out as per below.

```
Collections.sort(YourArrayList);
```

Comment: Sorting I Have Done But the Listview Is Not Changing Based on Sorted Value Still Remain Same.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your adapter backing the ListView by that listview will automatically sort.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ArrayAdapter`, order the elements inside the array asociated whit the `adapter` by your integer and link the `adapter` to your listView.