# Sort in listview using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, listview-adapter

I want to sort listview on the basis of counter but i am unable to do that please any body help me on that.

Here i am sharing my code and screen shot.

This is the adapter which is linked to the listview

**Custom_adapter_group.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter_groups extends BaseAdapter {
        String phone = "";
        Button bttn_request;

        ArrayList<DiscoverModel> discoverModel;
        SharedPreference_Main sharedPreference;

        String[] result;
        String[] details;
        private Context context;
        private int[] prgmImages;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        public Database4 db4;
        private ArrayList<DiscoverModel> listupdate;
        protected int position;

        public CustomAdapter_groups(Context context,
                ArrayList<DiscoverModel> discoverModel) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.context = context;
            this.discoverModel = discoverModel;
            this.listupdate = listupdate;
            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) ((context))
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            db4 = new Database4(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return discoverModel.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return discoverModel.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder {
            TextView tv;
            ImageView img;
            TextView tv_pushcounter;

            private Holder() {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sharedPreference = new SharedPreference_Main(context);
            final Holder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new Holder();
                convertView = this.inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.fragment_others_list_view_elements, null);

                holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_foodibdhe);
                holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_foodie);
                holder.tv_pushcounter = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_pushcounter);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            if (discoverModel.get(position) != null) {

                holder.tv.setText(discoverModel.get(position).getGroupname());
                // //Condition for counter
                if (db4.getCounter(discoverModel.get(position).getGroupchatid()) == "0") {
                    holder.tv_pushcounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (db4.getCounter(discoverModel.get(position)
                        .getGroupchatid()) == "101") {
                    holder.tv_pushcounter.setText("100+");
                }

                holder.tv_pushcounter.setText(db4.getCounter(discoverModel.get(
                        position).getGroupchatid()));

                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(discoverModel.get(position).getGroupimage())
                        .resize(200, 200).centerCrop()
                        .transform(new CircleTransform())
                        .into(holder.img, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                holder.img
                                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.group_friend_list_icon);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                            }
                        });
            }
            String update1 = sharedPreference.getlistupdate1();

            // if (!update1.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            // discoverModel.add(0, discoverModel.get(position));
            // discoverModel.
            // notifyDataSetChanged();
            // }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(context,
                            Private_group_chat_activity.class);

                    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference_Main(context);
                    sharedPreference.is_slient(""
                            + discoverModel.get(position).getIs_slient());

                    i.putExtra("public_group", "1");
                    i.putExtra("isMember", ""
                            + discoverModel.get(position).getIsMember());
                    i.putExtra("groupidentify", ""
                            + discoverModel.get(position).getGroup_identify());
                    i.putExtra("public_priavte_Identify",
                            "" + discoverModel.get(position).getPublic_private());
                    i.putExtra("groupchatid", ""
                            + discoverModel.get(position).getGroupchatid());
                    i.putExtra("groupname", ""
                            + discoverModel.get(position).getGroupname());
                    i.putExtra("groupId", ""
                            + discoverModel.get(position).getGroupid());
                    i.putExtra("isAdmin", ""
                            + discoverModel.get(position).getIsAdmin());
                    context.startActivity(i);

                    // discoverModel.add(0, discoverModel.get(position));
                    // notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return convertView;

            Collections.sort(discoverModel, myComparator);


        }

        public Comparator<Database4> myComparator = new Comparator<Database4>() {
            public int compare(Database4 obj1, Database4 obj2) {
                return obj1
                        .getCounter(discoverModel.get(position).getGroupchatid())
                        .compareTo(
                                obj2.getCounter(discoverModel.get(position)
                                        .getGroupchatid()));
            }
        };


    }
```

> Here is the code where ListView is used

**Fragment_groups.java**

```
public class Fragment_groups extends  Fragment implements ApiConstants,UpdateListener
            {
        private static int FLAG = 0;
        private ListView lv_list_view;
        private RelativeLayout rl_foodie;
        private EditText et_type_groups;
        private Database2 db2;
        private Database4 db4;
        private String newResponse;
        private String counter;
        private Button bttn_create_private_group;
        private ArrayList<DiscoverModel> discoverModel;
        private ArrayList<DiscoverModel> listupdate;
        private CustomAdapter_groups CustomAdapter_groups;
        SharedPreference_Main sharedPreference;
        public ArrayList<DiscoverModel> discoverModelSearch;
        public ArrayList<DiscoverModel> discoverModelStore;
        Activity activity;
        // Fragment_groups context;
        public static int\[\] prgmImages = { R.drawable.group_chat_icon,
                R.drawable.group_chat_icon, R.drawable.group_chat_icon };

        public static String\[\] prgmNameList = { "Foodie", "Football" };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,

        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            sharedPreference = new SharedPreference_Main(getActivity());

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_others, container, false);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //      this.setUpdatedCounter();
            activity = this.getActivity();
            lv_list_view = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_list_view);
            et_type_groups = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.et_type_groups);
            discoverModel = new ArrayList<DiscoverModel>();
            listupdate = new ArrayList<DiscoverModel>();
            discoverModelSearch = new ArrayList<DiscoverModel>();
            discoverModelStore = new ArrayList<DiscoverModel>();
            db2 = new Database2(getActivity());
            db4 = new Database4(getActivity());

            bttn_create_private_group = (Button) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.bttn_create_private_group);
            bttn_create_private_group.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Private_group.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            et_type_groups.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    searchText(s.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            get_groups_api();
            isOnline();
            return v;

        }

        private void isOnline() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Internet connection!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                newResponse = db2.getResponse(getActivity(), newResponse, 3);
                jsonparsing(newResponse);

            }
            return;
        }

        public void get_groups_api() {
            FLAG = 0;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    "http://unichatapi.approutes.com:80/groups",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            pDialog.hide();
                            discoverModel.clear();
                            // parsing method passing the response
                            Log.e("groups response", "" + response);
                            jsonparsing(response);

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            pDialog.hide();
                            VolleyLog.e("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("deviceId", sharedPreference.getRegisteration_id());
                    params.put("sessionId", "" + sharedPreference.getSession());
                    params.put("option", "getGroups");
                    params.put("userId", "" + sharedPreference.getUserId());
                    params.put("unixTime", "" + 0);

                    return params;
                }
            };
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sr);

        }

        protected void jsonparsing(String response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db2.update(response, 2, "1");
            try {

                JSONObject jsonO = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.e("message", "" + jsonO.getString("message"));
                Log.e("serverTime", "" + jsonO.getString("serverTime"));
                sharedPreference.server_time(jsonO.getString("serverTime"));

                // code for public group
                JSONArray publicgroupsA = jsonO.getJSONArray("publicGroups");
                for (int i = 0; i < publicgroupsA.length(); i++) {

                    DiscoverModel cm = new DiscoverModel();
                    JSONObject public_groupO = publicgroupsA.getJSONObject(i);

                    // if(sharedPreference.getlistupdate1().equalsIgnoreCase(public_groupO.getString("groupChatId")))
                    // {
                    // listupdate.add(cm);
                    // }

                    DiscoverModel dm = new DiscoverModel();
                    dm.setGroup_identify("1");
                    dm.setPublic_private("0");
                    dm.setIs_slient(public_groupO.getString("is_silent"));
                    dm.setGroupid(public_groupO.getString("groupId"));
                    Log.e("groupId", "" + public_groupO.getString("groupId"));
                    dm.setGroupname(public_groupO.getString("groupName"));
                    Log.e("groupName", "" + public_groupO.getString("groupName"));
                    dm.setGroupimage("http://unichatapi.approutes.com/vchatfiles/"
                            + public_groupO.getString("groupImage"));
                    dm.setGroupchatid(public_groupO.getString("groupChatId"));

    //              counter = db4.getCounter(dm.getGroupchatid());
                    Log.e("value from counter",""+counter);
    //              dm.setPushcounter(counter);

                    dm.setGroup_modified_on(public_groupO.getString("modifiedOn"));
                    dm.setGroup_created_on(public_groupO.getString("createdOn"));
                    discoverModel.add(dm);
                    db4.insertIncidentDetails(getActivity(), dm);



                }

                // code for private group
                JSONArray fullDataA = jsonO.getJSONArray("fullData");
                for (int j = 0; j < fullDataA.length(); j++) {
                    DiscoverModel fm = new DiscoverModel();
                    JSONObject jsongroup = fullDataA.getJSONObject(j);
                    fm.setGroup_identify("2");
                    fm.setPublic_private("1");
                    fm.setGroupid(jsongroup.getString("groupId"));
                    fm.setIsMember(jsongroup.getString("isMember"));
                    fm.setIsAdmin(jsongroup.getString("isAdmin"));
                    fm.setGroupname(jsongroup.getString("groupName"));
                    fm.setGroupimage("http://unichatapi.approutes.com/vchatfiles/"
                            + jsongroup.getString("groupImage"));
                    fm.setGroupchatid(jsongroup.getString("groupChatId"));
                    fm.setGroup_modified_on(jsongroup.getString("modifiedOn"));
                    fm.setGroup_created_on(jsongroup.getString("createdOn"));

                    Log.e("groupid", "" + jsongroup.getString("groupId"));
                    Log.e("groupName", "" + jsongroup.getString("groupName"));
                    Log.e("groupImage", "" + jsongroup.getString("groupImage"));
                    Log.e("groupChatId", "" + jsongroup.getString("groupChatId"));
                    Log.e("modifiedOn", "" + jsongroup.getString("modifiedOn"));
                    Log.e("createdOn", "" + jsongroup.getString("createdOn"));

                    discoverModel.add(fm);
                    db4.insertIncidentDetails(getActivity(), fm);
                    // CustomAdapter_groups.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                CustomAdapter_groups = new CustomAdapter_groups(getActivity(),
                        discoverModel);
                lv_list_view.setAdapter(CustomAdapter_groups);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        public LayoutInflater getSystemService(String layoutInflaterService) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.vchat"));
        }
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }

        public void searchText(String chartext) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            chartext = chartext.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            if (FLAG == 0) {
                discoverModelStore.clear();
                discoverModelStore.addAll(discoverModel);
                FLAG = 1;
            }
            discoverModelSearch.clear();
            discoverModelSearch.addAll(discoverModelStore);
            discoverModel.clear();
            if (chartext.length() == 0) {
                // discoverModel.clear();
                discoverModel.addAll(discoverModelStore);
                CustomAdapter_groups.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (chartext.length() >= 0) {
                // discoverModel.clear();

                for (DiscoverModel dm : discoverModelSearch) {
                    if (dm.getGroupname().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(chartext)) {
                        discoverModel.add(dm);
                    }
                }

            }
            CustomAdapter_groups.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void setUpdatedCounter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CustomAdapter_groups.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };




    }
```

> here is the screen shot of screen

[image]

Comment: You are actually sorting after return statement.
first sort it then pass data to adapter why every time you want to sort data ?

Comment: @androidnoobdev I can not set because i am setting counter directely from database in adapter and when ever push notification come the value of conter change and according that list view also get sort

Comment: See adapter is not going to get event directly i mean when push notification comes you are going to update adapter data so what i am telling is when you get data from push or db, sort list data and then pass it to your adapter and call notifydatasetchange method.
After return statement your code is not going to even run so i think compiler will even show you error.

Answer (score 0):

Try sort list in desc order, use this

```
            Collections.sort(myIntegerList, new Comparator<Integer>() {
                public int compare(Integer one, Integer other) {
                     if (one >= other) {
                         return -1;
                     } else {
                         return 1;
                     } 
                   }
            });
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18187719/2826147) for more detail.