# How to sort Array list integer type

Tags: java, android, sorting, android-studio, arraylist

I have an object class Product as shown below

```
public class Product {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    int price;
    String id;
    String image;
}
```

I want to sort the products with the basis of price.
my array is

```
 List<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();

 for(int i=0;i<ja3.length();i++){
     JSONObject jsonObject=ja3.getJSONObject(i);
     Product product=new Product();
     product.setId(jsonObject.getString("product_id"));
     product.setImage("http://ezybzy.com/images/"+jsonObject.getString("product_id")+"/1.jpg");
     product.setPrice(jsonObject.getInt("product_SP"));
     product.setName(jsonObject.getString("product_name"));
     products.add(product)
 }
```

I did

```
Collections.sort(products, new Comparator<Product>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Product lhs, Product rhs) {
        return lhs.getPrice().compareTo(rhs.getPrice());
    }
})
```

But the issue is that `.compareTo(rhs.getPrice()` part is in error.It cant use `compareTo` method.I want my arrayList sorted in the basis of the price of the product.The price is the integer value.But when I Changed it to String type I got `CompareTo` but its still unsorted because of the String type.Please Help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109890/android-java-how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-by-a-certain-value-within-the-object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709803/java-comparator-how-to-sort-by-integer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(products, new Comparator< Product >() {
    @Override public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
        return p1.getPrice()- p2.getPrice(); // Ascending
    }
});
```

Notice that this is a comparison between Integers, so no need to change it to String

Comment: @Richardo if we try this you will get a actual value like val1-val2 it does not return me 0 or 1 or -1

Answer (score 3):

Here are **three** values you can return from compare function

- 0
- Positive e.g 1
- Negative e.g -1

Positive value indicates that first object (p1 in this case) is greater than second object (p2 in this case) and vice versa. 0 shows that objects are equal

So for ascending order, you can override compare as

```
Collections.sort(products, new Comparator< Product >() {
    @Override public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
        return p1.getPrice()- p2.getPrice(); // Ascending
    }
});
```

for descending order

```
Collections.sort(products, new Comparator< Product >() {
    @Override public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
        return p2.getPrice()- p1.getPrice(); // Descending
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement Comparable in your Model class like this -

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    int price;
    String id;
    String image;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product another) {
        return getPrice() - another.getPrice();
    }
}
```

And then where ever you are using sort, you can use only sort functionality-

```
Collections.sort(products);
```

Comment: if I want to sort with name What I should do.Without removing price sorting fuction?

Comment: instead of getPrice use getName. You can change it as per your requirement. If it is String of that object then override toString() method and use toString().compareTo(another.toString()) as return value within that function.

Comment: But When I implements Comparable only sort by one at a time right?

Comment: Ya one at a time. But as you are implementing it, you can make it as per your needs. Like you can compare to of them at a time... First price then name... You have that option to code it out

Comment: I want sort with price and name at different time.How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add one more variable sort type and change it's value according to your need. Then use switch case in compareTo() or else you can use the piece of code that you have already marked right at different places

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `int` for the price you could simply substract prices instead of using `CompareTo`. If you are using strings I would first parse them to a double (or to an int, but double makes a little more sense for prices )`Double.parseDouble(rhs.getPrice())` and then substract them.

Answer (score 0):

For compareTo, you have to  use an object , It cannot work with int, If you want  it to work either cast it to Integer or simply use if condition for comparisons.

Answer (score -2):

Implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) interface in your object. And then you can use [Collections class sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method as follows:

```
List<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();
Collections.sort(products);
```