# Understanding a custom comparator in Java

Tags: java, comparator

I created a custom comparator which sorts the number of wins in descending order but im not sure how this works, can anyone explain me how this sorts according to descending order?

```
public static Comparator<FootballClub> sortNumOfWins = new Comparator<FootballClub>() {

    public int compare(FootballClub footballClub1, FootballClub footballClub2) {

        int numOfWins1 = footballClub1.getNumOfWins();
        int numOfWins2 = footballClub2.getNumOfWins();

        /*Returns the number of goals scored in  descending order*/
        return numOfWins2 - numOfWins1;
    }
};
```

Comment: [Optimising the `compareTo` method...](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/sorting_comparable_optimisation.shtml)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java comparator, how to sort by integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709803/java-comparator-how-to-sort-by-integer)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn that you’re expected to search before posting a question here, and/or check the tutorial or other docs. In many cases that will give you a better answer faster than anyone can type just a short answer here. And you will avoid the many downvotes. If your search is not enough, tell us what you found and how it fell short of solving your problem. Showing an effort on your part will make a lot of users prepared to do a greater effort on theirs. And they will what it is you need to know, providing for answers that are more helpful to you.

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you for those links, it pretty much helped me understand the logic behind this comparator

Answer (score 3):

## `Comparator#compare`

What is the goal of the [`Comparator#compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) method?

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Given your formula of `( numOfWins2  - numOfWins1 )`:

- For the case of numOfWins1 = 30 and numOfWins2 = 20, ( 20 - 30 ) is -10, a *negative* number. So the first should be sorted *after* the second.
- For the case of numOfWins1 = 20 and numOfWins2 = 30, ( 30 - 20 ) is
  10, a *positive* number. So the first should be sorted *above* the second.
- For the case of numOfWins1 = 25 and numOfWins2 = 25, ( 25 - 25 ) is
  0, zero. So the two items are tied for sorting.

## Complete example

Here is some example code. You can tweak the constructors of Alice and Carol to see the sorting in action.

This code uses the new compact [`record`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) definition of a class. This is a feature coming to Java 16. But using `record` is beside the point of this Answer. You can just as well use a conventional class definition.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Comparing
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Comparing app = new Comparing();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        List < FootballClub > clubs =
                List.of(
                        new FootballClub( "Alice" , 25 ) ,
                        new FootballClub( "Bob" , 7 ),
                        new FootballClub( "Carol" , 25 )
                );

        Comparator < FootballClub > sortByWinsDescending = new Comparator < FootballClub >()
        {

            public int compare ( FootballClub footballClub1 , FootballClub footballClub2 )
            {

                int numOfWins1 = footballClub1.wins();
                int numOfWins2 = footballClub2.wins();

                /* Returns the number of goals scored in  descending order */
                return numOfWins2 - numOfWins1;
            }
        };

        List < FootballClub > sorted = new ArrayList <>( clubs );
        sorted.sort( sortByWinsDescending );

        System.out.println( "clubs = " + clubs );
        System.out.println( "sorted = " + sorted );
    }

    record FootballClub(String name , Integer wins)
    {
    }
}
```

## Not recommended

This code `return ( numOfWins2  - numOfWins1 ) ;` is the kind of “clever” programming that should be avoided. This code is confusing and troublesome. I even confused myself while writing this Answer.

Better would be letting objects compare themselves. In my example code, we use the class `Integer`. Well, `Integer` objects already know how to compare themselves. So call [`Integer#compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer)).

```
return footballClub1.wins().compareTo( footballClub2.wins() ) ;
```

Or in the case of `int` primitives as seen in your code, call the static utility method [`Integer.compare( int x , int y )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)):

```java
        int numOfWins1 = footballClub1.getNumOfWins();
        int numOfWins2 = footballClub2.getNumOfWins();

        /* Returns the number of goals scored in  descending order */
        return Integer.compare ( numOfWins1 , numOfWins2 ) ;
```

By the way, we can look at [the OpenJDK source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) to see how this [`Integer.compare( int x , int y )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)) method is implemented. They use a nested pair of [ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#Computer_science). A `?:` ternary works this way: If the predicate test is true, use item following the `?`, else if false use the item following the `:`.

```
// Copyright (c) 1994, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
// Excerpt from https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java
// See licensing terms in that original file.
return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
```

Make a habit of writing code this is as plain and simple as possible. Humans spend much more time *reading* code than *writing* code. On a job, when you have a bug in one of your report-generating methods, and you are debugging in the middle of the night, you do *not* want to be trying to figure out if `return numOfWins2 - numOfWins1` is for ascending or descending.

As a bonus, plain and simple code that is readable by humans is often more likely to be an opportunity for the Java compiler and runtime to optimize for performance.

---

For fun, add this line before your `return` statement to see the individual comparisons.

```
System.out.println( "numOfWins1: " + numOfWins1 + " | numOfWins2: " + numOfWins2 + " | numOfWins2 - numOfWins1: " + ( numOfWins2 - numOfWins1 ) );
```

---

## Ascending order

Tip: If you wanted *ascending* order rather than descending, just multiply the result of that call `Integer#compareTo` or `Integer.compare` by negative 1 (`-1`). Doing so flips the sign of the result, negative becomes positive, positive becomes negative, and zero remains zero.

```java
return ( -1 * Integer.compare ( numOfWins1 , numOfWins2 ) ) ;  // Ascending rather than descending sort order.
```

### Method reference

As [Ole V.V. commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757720/understanding-a-custom-comparator-in-java#comment116263763_65757767), if you are comfortable with lambdas and method references, you can collapse your entire `Comparator` implementation to a single-line solution for ascending sort by calling [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)).

```
Comparator < FootballClub > sortByWinsDescending = Comparator.comparingInt( FootballClub :: wins );
```

Our example above becomes quite shorter.

```java
package work.basil.example;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Comparing2
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Comparing2 app = new Comparing2();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        List < FootballClub > clubs =
                List.of(
                        new FootballClub( "Alice" , 20 ) ,
                        new FootballClub( "Bob" , 7 ) ,
                        new FootballClub( "Carol" , 30 )
                );

        Comparator < FootballClub > sortByWinsDescending = Comparator.comparingInt( FootballClub :: wins );

        List < FootballClub > sorted = new ArrayList <>( clubs );
        sorted.sort( sortByWinsDescending );

        System.out.println( "clubs = " + clubs );
        System.out.println( "sorted = " + sorted );
    }

    record FootballClub(String name , Integer wins)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: "return Integer.compare ( numOfWins1 , numOfWins2 )"  will sort the Array in Ascending order not descending order as you mentioned above.   Multiplying by -1 will sort these in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    public static Comparator<FootballClub> sortNumOfWins = new Comparator<FootballClub>() {

    public int compare(FootballClub footballClub1, FootballClub footballClub2) {

        Integer numOfWins1 = footballClub1.getNumOfWins();
        Integer numOfWins2 = footballClub2.getNumOfWins();

        return numOfWins2.compareTo(numOfWins1);
    }
};
```

when you compare integer field only and this compare is typical, you can use standard method compareTo from Integer type.

Comment: This does not answer the question that the OP asked.

Comment: It’s good advice, but as@StephenC said, doesn’t answer the question. And still better is just `Comparator.comparingInt(FootballClub::getNumOfWins)`.

Answer (score 0):

The return value tells the caller which item is 'bigger' (or if they are equals)

```
1 : numOfWins1 < numOfWins2
0 : numOfWins1 == numOfWins2
-1 : numOfWins1 > numOfWins2
```

(the positive 1 or negative 1 can also be other integers, like -2/2,  -100/100, any positive/negative number)

so, when you return:

```
return numOfWins2 - numOfWins1;
```

it will be a **positive** number if numOfWins2 > numOfWins1,

**negative** number if numOfWins2 < numOfWins1

and **0** if numOfWins2 == numOfWins1